# WordPress, send articles by facebook messenger each day

Tags: wordpress, facebook, messenger

I have a wordpress website who publish articles, i want to automacaly send a selection of articles to users in their facebook messenger

I saw a website that do that, and I want to do same

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a Wordpress Plugin for that, but I would do it like so:

1. Creating a cronjob and executing a php file once a day. (How this works in WP: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/optimization-and-configuration/wordpress2/configuring-a-cron-job-for-wordpress)
2. This file is getting all the new posts (or maybe posts with a specific WP Tag or whatever you want to send to your users) from the WP API.
3. Then, in this file, you connect to the Facebook Send API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/ and send this posts to your users. Read the API  docs for how that actually works

Comment: i create an app but if i'm the one who send message, i can see that message from my website
but if it's another person who write the message to the page, it doesnt trigger the webhhok url file

Comment: is your app approved by facebook?